# C++ Making a computer guess a number

Tags: c++, count, binary

Trying to figure out how I can get the computer to guess a 9 digit binary number 7 times and when it's correct to output that the number which is entered is correct.

Also if anyone knows how to count the number of 0s and 1s in the binary number that would be appreciated I tried reading on std::count() but didn't understand it as I am very new to c++.

Cheers.

```
 void breakyourcode()
    {
        cout << "You have picked break your code" << endl;
        string guess;
        int tries = 7;
        srand(time(NULL));
        int index = rand() % 512;
        string cGuess = index2code(index);
        cout << cGuess << endl;

        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> guess;

        do {
            cout << "\nComputer's guess: " << endl;
            cout << cGuess;
            ++tries;

            if (guess == cGuess) {
                cout << "Yeeha! I won!" << endl;
                system("PAUSE");
                break;
            }
            cGuess = rand() % 512;

        } while (guess != cGuess);

        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my interpretation of your question I assumed you want an unsigned number -- though I guess this should work with signed integers just as well.

Another assumption I take is that you want the user to input numbers as ones and zeroes, which is put into a string and then converted into an `unsigned` integer by function `convertBinaryNumberStringToInt`.

Here goes some code suggesting how you could do it, including the function `howManyOnes`, made specifically for counting how many ones are there in the binary form of your number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// For CHAR_BIT
#include <climits>

// For std::reverse, but you could
// write your own string reverse function
#include <algorithm>

unsigned convertBinaryNumberStringToInt(const std::string& stringNumber)
{
    unsigned outputNumber = 0;

    // Using a reversed string allows us to insert ones in the
    // number's binary form from right to left while still using
    // a range-based for loop with not much tinkering
    std::string reversedStrNum = stringNumber;
    std::reverse(reversedStrNum.begin(), reversedStrNum.end());


    unsigned i = 1;

    // i starts as 00000000000000000000000000000001 (binary, assuming 32 bits integer)
    // On each iteration of the for loop, the 1 is shifted left and,
    // if the current character is '1', the value 1 is copied into
    // its corresponding current position in outputNumber
    for(char c : reversedStrNum)
    {
        if(c == '1')
        {
            // The bitwise-or operation copies the 1 in i to
            // its corresponding position in outputNumber
            outputNumber = outputNumber | i;

        }
        // Shift i's 1 to the left by one position
        i = i << 1;
        // You could also do i *= 2, but we're specifically shifting
        // bits, so the bitshift seems more "semantic"
    }

    return outputNumber;
}

bool isStringCorrect(std::string& userString, size_t maxSize)
{
    if(userString.size() > 9)
        return false;

    for(char c : userString)
        if(c != '1' && c != '0')
            return false;

    return true;
}

unsigned computerGuess(unsigned highBound)
{
    return rand() % highBound;
}

unsigned howManyOnes(unsigned number)
{
    unsigned count = 0;
    unsigned shifter = 1;

    // For each bit: sizeof(unsigned) is the size in bytes
    // of an unsigned, CHAR_BIT is the bit length of a char or byte
    // So we loop through each bit position.
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT * sizeof(unsigned); i++)
    {
        // What we do is we test our number against the shifter
        // for each bit position. If a bitwise-and between both
        // is non-zero, it means number has 1 in that position,
        // so we increase the "one" count.
        if((number & shifter) != 0)
            ++count;

        // Either way, we left-shift the one in shifter afterwards
        shifter = shifter << 1;
    }

    return count;
}

int main()
{
    std::string userChoiceNumberString;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> userChoiceNumberString;

    if(!isStringCorrect(userChoiceNumberString, 9))
    {
        std::cout << "Entered string is incorrect" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    unsigned userChoiceNumber = convertBinaryNumberStringToInt(userChoiceNumberString);

    std::cout << "Your number has " << howManyOnes(userChoiceNumber) << " ones in binary." << std::endl;

    int attempts = 7;
    while(attempts > 0)
    {
        if(computerGuess(512) == userChoiceNumber)
        {
            std::cout << "Yeeha! I won!" << std::endl;
            attempts = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Hmmm... guessed wrong..." << std::endl;
            --attempts;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```